# elasticsearch 7xx exceptions.RequestError

Tags: elasticsearch

Help me please to resolve the problem with elasticsearch.
After install this package https://github.com/nyaadevs/nyaa the search with elasticsearch not working. config.yml was created for old version of elasticsearch < 6. Now version of elastic is latest (7xx).

[image]

config.yml

```
settings:
  analysis:
    analyzer:
      my_search_analyzer:
        type: custom
        tokenizer: standard
        char_filter:
          - my_char_filter
        filter:
          - lowercase
      my_index_analyzer:
        type: custom
        tokenizer: standard
        char_filter:
          - my_char_filter
        filter:
          - resolution
          - lowercase
          - word_delimit
          - my_ngram
          - trim_zero
          - unique
      # For exact matching - separate each character for substring matching + lowercase
      exact_analyzer:
        tokenizer: exact_tokenizer
        filter:
          - lowercase
      # For matching full words longer than the ngram limit (15 chars)
      my_fullword_index_analyzer:
        type: custom
        tokenizer: standard
        char_filter:
          - my_char_filter
        filter:
          - lowercase
          - word_delimit
          # Skip tokens shorter than N characters,
          # since they're already indexed in the main field
          - fullword_min
          - unique

    tokenizer:
      # Splits input into characters, for exact substring matching
      exact_tokenizer:
        type: pattern
        pattern: "(.)"
        group: 1

    filter:
      my_ngram:
        type: edgeNGram
        min_gram: 1
        max_gram: 15
      fullword_min:
        type: length
        # Remember to change this if you change the max_gram below!
        min: 16
      resolution:
        type: pattern_capture
        patterns: ["(\\d+)[xX](\\d+)"]
      trim_zero:
        type: pattern_capture
        patterns: ["0*([0-9]*)"]
      word_delimit:
        type: word_delimiter
        preserve_original: true
        split_on_numerics: false
    char_filter:
      my_char_filter:
        type: mapping
        mappings: ["-=>_", "!=>_", "_=>\\u0020"]
  index:
    id_field: integer
    sort.order: desc
    # we're running a single es node, so no sharding necessary,
    # plus replicas don't really help either.
    number_of_shards: 1
    number_of_replicas : 0
    # since we disabled the _all field, default query the
    # name of the torrent.
    query:
      default_field: display_name
mappings:
  properties:
    title:
      type: text
      boost: 2
    content:
      type: text
    id:
      type: integer
```

It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.

Comment: Elasticsearch 7.X has some breaking changes, is the package you are trying to use compatible with version 7.X? If not, there is not much you can do besides opening an issue on their github or try to fix the code to make it compatible.

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar w/ nyaa but `id_field: integer` looks suspicious.

Shouldn't it be `id_field: id`?